# How can I move bitcoin-qt blockchain data to bitcoind daemon?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I have a bunch of files like blk00110.dat now that bitcoin-qt (on my mac) has finally updated. I'd like to just move this over to my linux box so I can keep it up and running but the bitcoind program uses a different structure. How can I move this data?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `.bitcoin` directory once you install bitcoind on your linux box. Copying those `.dat` files in this directory should enable bitcoind to read them directly.

Bitcoin-QT is actually using bitcoind under the hood. So it shouldn't be using different structure unless you're using different versions of bitcoind.

Edit: also reading more about [bitcoind commands](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Command-line_arguments), there's a command to import a file directly. So this should probably be better than directly placing the files in the directory:

`bitcoind -loadblock=<file>`      `Imports blocks from external blk000??.dat file`

Comment: There are a lot of those blk files though. Importing I'd have to do it one by one and that way it probably verifies them so it's slower. I'll try to copy directly to the folder I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate all the blk files (in order) and put them in bootstrap.dat, and copy that over to ~/.bitcoin/ - then bitcoind will import it.